# what schema evolution should I use while using quill-async-mysql and play 2.6?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, quill.io

Im using `quill-async-mysql` in my project, and I have a simple db setup in my `application.conf`:

```
quilldb {
  host = 127.0.0.1
  port = 3306
  user = root
  password = ""
  database = MyDatabaseName
}
```

thats it.

And now I want to add some kind of schema evolution to handle my db creations and stuff, and in looking for

a library that will play along nicely with quill-async-mysql and `playframework`, does anyone hav e some good recommendations?

I heard about flyway but it uses `jdbc` connection and im using `quill-async-mysql`, and also looked at `playframework` evolutions but had some difficulties with the

setup, so I would appreciate any help.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using **quill-async-postgress** and **Flyway** for the migrations, by having two alternative db connections in application.conf, one is used just for Flyway. If you don't mind including jdbc in your build, it is quite straightforward.